# java opening a socket on the client side

Tags: java, sockets, listener

i can't figure out why my client socket keeps falling in an IOException.
When it falls in the IOException i recreate my socket and so it will work again untill it falls again into the Exception and so on ...

the code should always read out an ip controller from my electrical installation. I cant change anything on the server side. I connect to it and when something happens it post it to the port and i want to be able to read it.

this is the opening socket code

```
    public KnxController(){
    try{
        System.out.println("Server started");
        clientSocket = new Socket(IP, PORT);
        outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.out.println("UnknownHostException: kan knx niet vinden");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOException knxcontroller: kan geen data sturen");
    }
```

and here i read out the data

```
        while(true){
        try {
            DataInputStream din=new DataInputStream(knxC.clientSocket.getInputStream()); 
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(din));
            String[] str=br.readLine().split("");  
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            try {
                knxC.clientSocket = new Socket(knxC.IP, knxC.PORT);
            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch(NullPointerException nex){
            try {
                knxC.clientSocket = new Socket(knxC.IP, knxC.PORT);
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }       
    }
```

it workes but far from good coding.
any help on how to solve this would be appreciated.

Comment: Not familiar with KNX Standard. I only can suggest to check if: Maybe it is totally normal for a server to close the connection after one transaction. Or the Server may have some "Idle" connection timeout. Some protocols have some "NOP"-operation or keepalive mechanisms for that. If KNX hasn't, then you can certainly work around somehow. Nonetheless you should handle connection failure anyway.

Comment: that's a great answer, there is indeed a communication alive bit i can activate,

Comment: "falling in an IOException" -> please post the stack trace + exception message of the IOException that is _thrown_

Answer (score 1):

cleaned the above code for anyone who's interested

opening a socket

```
    public KnxController(){
    do{
        setClientSocket();

        try {
            outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("IOException knxcontroller: kan geen data out stream starten naar knx");
        } catch (NullPointerException nEx){
            log.error("NullPointerException knxcontroller: geen knx host");
        }
    }while(clientSocket == null);

    KnxSocketListener knxL = new KnxSocketListener("KnxSocketListener", this);
    knxL.start();
}

    public void setClientSocket() {
    try {
        this.clientSocket = new Socket(IP, PORT);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        log.error("UnknownHostException: kan geen socket opbouwen met knx host");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("IOException: kan geen socket opbouwen met knx host");
    }
}
```

socketlistener in new thread public class KnxSocketListener

```
public KnxSocketListener(String name, KnxController knxC) {
      threadName = name;
      System.out.println("Creating " +  threadName );
      this.knxC = knxC;
}

public void start () {
      System.out.println("Starting " +  threadName );
      if (t == null) {
         t = new Thread (this, threadName);
         t.start ();
      }
}   

public void run()
{
    while(true){
        try {
            DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(knxC.getClientSocket().getInputStream()); 
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(din));
            String[] str=br.readLine().split("");  
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            knxC.setClientSocket();
        } catch(NullPointerException nex){
            knxC.setClientSocket();
        }       
    }
}
```